# Super-Alt-8 and Super-Alt-+ scales too much

Tags: gnome

Is there any way to reduce the amount of magnification performed by the Super-Alt-+ key? When I press this once the screen is magnified by an enormous amount! On Mac there is a way to just magnify a bit. Is there a way to do this on Gnome 3.28.2 (Ubuntu 18.04)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible. Delta values +1 and -1 are "hardcoded" and can't be changed. Maybe in future versions it will change. If that helps you can define the initial scale factor by running `gsetting` command.

**Super-Alt-8 keeps original window unchanged:**

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier mag-factor 1.00

**Super-Alt-8 original window zoomed a little:**

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier mag-factor 1.25

`mag-factor` value can also be changed from "Magnifier Preferences Dialog" as found in "Universal Access Panel". Just type "Universal Access" in GNOME search box and look for ZOOM options.

For more information follow link:

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Magnification